# NullPointerException when trying to access Database

Tags: database, jsf, netbeans, primefaces, nullpointerexception

I am trying to create a mindmap-style application using:

Netbeans 7.2
jdk 6.35
Primefaces 3.4

The idea is to generate the mindmap by accessing a database and generating the nodes from that database. I have ensured that the program generates a suitable graphic from objects of the same type as that which I am trying to access. However, when I try to access the database info, I get a NullPointerException. The steps I used in generating the generic pages were:

1) Created the databases and populated them.
2) Used the "New Entities Classes From Database" feature in netbeans.
3) Used the "JSF Pages from Entity Classes" feature.
4) Created a JSF Managed Bean to generate the mindmap.

Here is the code for the mindmap Bean:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package jsf;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import jpa.entities.Enginetable;
import jpa.session.EnginetableFacade;
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.mindmap.DefaultMindmapNode;
import org.primefaces.model.mindmap.MindmapNode;

/**
 *
 * @author AOL
 */
@Named(value = "mmBean")
@RequestScoped
public class mmBean {


    private MindmapNode root;

    private MindmapNode selectedNode;

    private List<Enginetable> elements;
    private List<Enginetable> filteredElements;
    private List<Enginetable> userlist;

    private Enginetable selectedElement;
    private Enginetable[] selectedElements; 


    private List<Enginetable> elementlist = new ArrayList<Enginetable>();

    private Enginetable nodeentity = new Enginetable();
    private Enginetable rootentity = new Enginetable();
    private Enginetable userentity = new Enginetable();


    private jpa.session.EnginetableFacade ejbFacade;

    private static final String[] username;

    static{

        username = new String[10];  
        username[0] = "Mercedes";  
        username[1] = "BMW";  
        username[2] = "Volvo";  
        username[3] = "Audi";  
        username[4] = "Renault";  
        username[5] = "Opel";  
        username[6] = "Volkswagen";  
        username[7] = "Chrysler";  
        username[8] = "Ferrari";  
        username[9] = "Ford";  
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of MmBean
     */
    public mmBean() {
        ///if(elements==null){
        elements = new ArrayList<Enginetable>(); 
        //} 
        //remoteuser=null;
        // this.populateRandomElements(elements, 10); 
        this.populateRandomElements(elements,6);  

        // filteredElements = new ArrayList<Graphelement>();
        root = new DefaultMindmapNode("Mercedes", "Google", "FFCC00", false);
        /*MindmapNode bmw = new DefaultMindmapNode("BMW", "IP Nos", "6e9ebf", true);
        MindmapNode volvo = new DefaultMindmapNode("Volvo", "Names", "6e9ebf", true);
        MindmapNode audi = new DefaultMindmapNode("Audi", "Malicious ", "6e9ebf", true);
        MindmapNode renault = new DefaultMindmapNode("Renault", "IP Nos", "6e9ebf", true);
        MindmapNode opel = new DefaultMindmapNode("Opel", "Names", "6e9ebf", true);
        MindmapNode volkwagen = new DefaultMindmapNode("Volkswagen", "Malicious ", "6e9ebf", true);
        MindmapNode chrysler = new DefaultMindmapNode("Chrysler", "IP Nos", "6e9ebf", true);
        MindmapNode ferrari = new DefaultMindmapNode("Ferrari", "Names", "6e9ebf", true);
        MindmapNode ford = new DefaultMindmapNode("Ford", "Malicious ", "6e9ebf", true);*/


        Object label = root.getLabel();
        Enginetable entity;


        for( int i = 0 ; i < this.elements.size() ; i++){

                    entity = this.elements.get(i);


                    if ( !label.equals(entity.getStartnode() ) && label.equals(entity.getEndnode() ) ) {

                            root.addNode(new DefaultMindmapNode(entity.getStartnode() , "Malicious Software: ", "00FF99", true));

                    } 

                    else if ( !label.equals(entity.getStartnode() ) && !label.equals(entity.getEndnode() ) ){

                            root.addNode(new DefaultMindmapNode(entity.getStartnode() , "Malicious Software: ", "CC0000", true));

                    }


                    else if ( label.equals(entity.getStartnode() ) ) {

                            this.rootentity.setStartnode( entity.getStartnode() );
                            this.rootentity.setEndnode( entity.getEndnode() );
                            this.rootentity.setConnections( entity.getConnections() );
                            this.rootentity.setGroupid( entity.getGroupid() );
                            this.rootentity.setMoveid( entity.getMoveid() );
                            this.rootentity.setNewconnectioncost( entity.getNewconnectioncost() );
                            this.rootentity.setNewinfovalue( entity.getNewinfovalue() );
                            this.rootentity.setUsername( entity.getUsername() );
                            this.rootentity.setUserid( entity.getUserid() );

                    } 
        }
    }

    public void setElements(List<Enginetable> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    public List<Enginetable> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }
    public void setFilteredElements(List<Enginetable> filteredElements) {
        //this.filteredElements = filteredElements;
        this.elements=filteredElements;
    }

    public List<Enginetable> getFilteredElements() {
        return filteredElements;
    }

    public void setSelectedElements(Enginetable[] selectedElements) {
        this.selectedElements = selectedElements;
    }

    public Enginetable[] getSelectedElements() {
        return selectedElements;
    }

    public void setSelectedElement(Enginetable selectedElement) {
        this.selectedElement = selectedElement;
    }

    public Enginetable getSelectedElement() {
        return selectedElement;
    }

    public MindmapNode getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public MindmapNode getSelectedNode() {
        return selectedNode;
    }
    public void setSelectedNode(MindmapNode selectedNode) {
        this.selectedNode = selectedNode;
    }



    public void onNodeSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        MindmapNode node = (MindmapNode) event.getObject();


            for( int i = 0 ; i < this.elements.size() ; i++){
                    Enginetable entity;
                    Object label = node.getLabel();
                    Object rootlabel = this.root.getLabel();

                    entity = elements.get(i);

                    if ( entity.getStartnode() == rootlabel ){
                        this.rootentity = entity;
                    }
                    if ( entity.getStartnode() == label ){
                        this.nodeentity = entity;
                    }

            }
    //load children of select node and add via node.addNode(childNode);
    //populate if not already loaded
        if(node.getChildren().isEmpty()) {


            for( int i = 0 ; i < this.elements.size() ; i++){
                    Enginetable entity;

                    entity = this.elements.get(i);

                    if ( (this.nodeentity.getStartnode() == null ? entity.getStartnode() != null : !this.nodeentity.getStartnode().equals(entity.getStartnode())) && (this.nodeentity.getEndnode() == null ? entity.getStartnode() != null : !this.nodeentity.getEndnode().equals(entity.getStartnode())) &&  (this.rootentity.getEndnode() == null ? entity.getStartnode() == null : this.rootentity.getEndnode().equals(entity.getStartnode()))  )  {

                            node.addNode(new DefaultMindmapNode(entity.getStartnode() , "Malicious Software: ", "33FF00", true));

                    } 

                     else if ( (this.nodeentity.getStartnode() == null ? entity.getStartnode() != null : !this.nodeentity.getStartnode().equals(entity.getStartnode())) && (this.nodeentity.getEndnode() == null ? entity.getStartnode() == null : this.nodeentity.getEndnode().equals(entity.getStartnode())) &&  (this.rootentity.getEndnode() == null ? entity.getStartnode() == null : this.rootentity.getEndnode().equals(entity.getStartnode()))  )  {

                            node.addNode(new DefaultMindmapNode(entity.getStartnode() , "Malicious Software: ", "3300FF", true));

                    }

                    else if ( (this.nodeentity.getStartnode() == null ? entity.getStartnode() != null : !this.nodeentity.getStartnode().equals(entity.getStartnode())) && (this.nodeentity.getEndnode() == null ? entity.getStartnode() == null : this.nodeentity.getEndnode().equals(entity.getStartnode())) &&  (this.rootentity.getEndnode() == null ? entity.getStartnode() != null : !this.rootentity.getEndnode().equals(entity.getStartnode()))  )  {

                            node.addNode(new DefaultMindmapNode(entity.getStartnode() , "Malicious Software: ", "FF9900", true));

                    }

                    else if ( (this.nodeentity.getStartnode() == null ? entity.getStartnode() != null : !this.nodeentity.getStartnode().equals(entity.getStartnode())) && (this.nodeentity.getEndnode() == null ? entity.getStartnode() != null : !this.nodeentity.getEndnode().equals(entity.getStartnode())) &&  (this.rootentity.getEndnode() == null ? entity.getStartnode() != null : !this.rootentity.getEndnode().equals(entity.getStartnode()))  )  {

                            node.addNode(new DefaultMindmapNode(entity.getStartnode() , "Malicious Software: ", "CC0000", true));

                    }

                }

            }
        }


    public void onNodeDblselect(SelectEvent event) {
        this.selectedNode = (MindmapNode) event.getObject();        
    }


    private EnginetableFacade getFacade() {
        return ejbFacade;
    }



    private void populateRandomElements(List<Enginetable> list, int size) { 
        userlist = this.getListByUserID( 1 );
        for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)  {

            if ("Chrysler".equals(username[i])){
                Random rand = new Random();
                Enginetable gel =new Enginetable();
                gel.setMoveid(i);
                gel.setUserid(i);
                gel.setStartnode(username[i]);
                gel.setEndnode(username[9]);
                gel.setConnections(username[9]);
         //       gel.setPurpose("dubious");
         //       gel.setRelationship("naughty");
         //       gel.setExperimentid(1);
                gel.setNewinfovalue(1);
                gel.setNewconnectioncost(1);
                list.add(gel);
            }

            else {
                Random rand = new Random();
                Enginetable gel =new Enginetable();
                gel.setMoveid(i);
                gel.setUserid(i);
                gel.setStartnode(username[i]);
                gel.setEndnode(username[9-i]);
                gel.setConnections(username[9-i]);
         //       gel.setPurpose("dubious");
         //       gel.setRelationship("naughty");
         //       gel.setExperimentid(1);
                gel.setNewinfovalue(1);
                gel.setNewconnectioncost(1);
                list.add(gel);                
            }
        }
    }

//


    public Integer getMoveId(Enginetable ent) {
        return ent.getMoveid();
    }

    public void setMoveId(Enginetable ent, Integer id) {
        ent.setMoveid(id);
    }

    public Integer getUserId(Enginetable ent) {
        return ent.getMoveid();
    }

    public void setUserId(Enginetable ent, Integer id) {
        ent.setMoveid(id);
    }

    public String getStartNode(Enginetable ent) {
        return ent.getStartnode();
    }

    public void setStartNode(Enginetable ent, String startnode) {
        ent.setStartnode(startnode);
    }

    public String getEndNode(Enginetable ent) {
        return ent.getEndnode();
    }

    public void setEndNode(Enginetable ent, String endnode) {
        ent.setEndnode(endnode);
    }

 /*   public int getExperimentid(Enginetable ent) {
        return ent.getExperimentid();
    }

    public void setExperimentid(Enginetable ent, int experimentid) {
        ent.setExperimentid(experimentid); 
    }*/

    public int getNewInfoValue(Enginetable ent) {
        return ent.getNewinfovalue();
    }

    public void setNewInfoValue(Enginetable ent, int totalinfovalue) {
        ent.setNewinfovalue(totalinfovalue);
    }

    public String getConnections(Enginetable ent) {
        return ent.getConnections();
    }

    public void setConnections(Enginetable ent, String connections) {
        ent.setConnections(connections);
    }

    public String getNewConnections(Enginetable ent) {
        return ent.getConnections();
    }

    public void setNewConnections(Enginetable ent, String newconnections) {
        ent.setConnections( newconnections );
    }

 /*   public String getUserName(Enginetable ent) {
        return ent.getUsername();
    }

    public void setUsername(Enginetable ent, String name) {
        ent.setUsername(name);
    }
 */
    public List<Enginetable> getListByUsername(String user){
       return this.ejbFacade.getEnginetableByUsername(user);
    } 

    public List<Enginetable> getListByUserID( int id ){
       if ( this.ejbFacade.getEnginetableByUserid(id) == null){
       throw new NullPointerException("admin is null!");
       }
       else if ( this.ejbFacade.getEnginetableByUserid(id) != null){
       List<Enginetable> list = new ArrayList<Enginetable>();
       list = this.ejbFacade.getEnginetableByUserid(id);
           return list;
       }
       else{
           List<Enginetable> list = new ArrayList<Enginetable>();
                Enginetable gel =new Enginetable();
                gel.setMoveid(1);
                gel.setUserid(1);
                gel.setStartnode(username[1]);
                gel.setEndnode(username[9]);
                gel.setConnections(username[9]);
         //       gel.setPurpose("dubious");
         //       gel.setRelationship("naughty");
         //       gel.setExperimentid(1);
                gel.setNewinfovalue(1);
                gel.setNewconnectioncost(1);
                list.add(gel);
           return list;
       }
    } 
}
```

For completeness, I have included the code of the classes it imports.

Edit: I removed the Enginetable class as I had too many characters to submit with stack trace. It was just get and set methods.

Here is the code for the EngineTableFacade class:
    package jpa.session;

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import jpa.entities.Enginetable;

/**
 *
 * @author AOL
 */
@Stateless
public class EnginetableFacade extends AbstractFacade<Enginetable> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Networks0.1PU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public EnginetableFacade() {
        super(Enginetable.class);
    }

    public List<Enginetable> getEnginetableByUsername( String username ) {
        try {
            List<Enginetable> userlist = (List<Enginetable>)
            em.createNamedQuery("Enginetable.findByUsername").
                    setParameter("Username", username).getResultList();
            return userlist; 
        } catch (NoResultException nre) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public List<Enginetable> getEnginetableByUserid( int id ) {
        try {
            List<Enginetable> userlist = (List<Enginetable>)
            em.createNamedQuery("Enginetable.findByUserid").
                    setParameter("Userid", id).getResultList();
            return userlist; 
        } catch (NoResultException nre) {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

This throws the NullPointerException when either the getListByUsername or getListByUserID methods are called, but works fine if they are not. Having checked the StackTrace, that confirms my idea that it's those two methods where the exception is being thrown from.

I suspect, although I'm not sure, that this means that the entity manager is null in mmBean. I am uncertain how, or even if, this can be corrected. Please, any advice would be hugely appreciated, I am very stuck and frustrated over this minor bridge that I *need* to cross but can't. Thank you.

Edited to include Stack trace:

```
com.google.common.collect.ComputationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:397)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.getClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:102)
        at org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:115)
        at org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.getValue(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:96)
        at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:188)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
        at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:103)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:179)
        at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
        at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
        at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
        at org.primefaces.component.mindmap.Mindmap.getValue(Mindmap.java:98)
        at org.primefaces.component.mindmap.MindmapRenderer.encodeScript(MindmapRenderer.java:51)
        at org.primefaces.component.mindmap.MindmapRenderer.encodeEnd(MindmapRenderer.java:44)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
        at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInstantiation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:186)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.newInstance(SecureReflections.java:341)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:242)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.createClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:87)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.access$000(ClientProxyProvider.java:43)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$1.apply(ClientProxyProvider.java:53)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$1.apply(ClientProxyProvider.java:46)
        at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:355)
        at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
        at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
        at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
        at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:393)
        ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at jsf.mmBean.getListByUserID(mmBean.java:360)
        at jsf.mmBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getListByUserID(mmBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
        at jsf.mmBean.populateRandomElements(mmBean.java:277)
        at jsf.mmBean.<init>(mmBean.java:74)
        at jsf.mmBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.<init>(mmBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$16.work(SecureReflections.java:344)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInstantiation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:173)
        ... 63 more
```

Comment: I've had this problem with Entity Framework in C#. I solved this by deleting the Entity Model and Adding it again. Hope this helps. Also, do the users of which you ask the list, have a list in the DB?

Comment: When you say deleting the Entity Model do you mean, in this case, the Enginetable class or the database? 

If I understand you correctly, yes the users have a list in the DB, going from id 1 to 6, and username A to F. If I have not understood you correctly, please, correct!

Comment: I mean the class that you genereted ("New Entities Classes From Database"). You understood me correctly, sorry for my poor English :)

Comment: could you extend your question with the relevant stack trace lines?

Comment: Of course, I apologise for not including it straight away.

And I did try deleting it and recreating it but it didn't work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject the ejb into the bean

```
@EJB
private jpa.session.EnginetableFacade ejbFacade;
```

Found some more problems with your mmBean, the stuff in the constructor should be moved into a postConstruct method (Because it is invoked after injects of EJB)

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    ... (code from constructor here)
}
```

Comment: I added that in but still have the same problem. That would definitely have caused a problem anyway though, so thank you.

Comment: can you add some stacktrace also?

Comment: Btw you would propably benefit from seting up a minimal example that just tests the whole chain from UI to DB, without having so many methods in the class. But on the other hand you might be almost there anyways. Tip for next time atleast

Comment: Thank you, this solved that problem! Now I have an issue that it can't recognise the usernames or ids that I'm entering as being a member of the database. "WELD-000049 Unable to invoke [method] @PostConstruct public jsf.mmBean.init() on jsf.mmBean@1ffc90a" is the error and "You have attempted to set a parameter value using a name of Username that does not exist in the query string SELECT e FROM Enginetable e WHERE e.username = :username." is from the stack trace. Thank you for solving the immediate issue though! More of a relief than you know, I think.

Comment: Never mind! I think I understand the other comment I got, asking if there was a list associated with a certain username, I think there probably wasn't. I can now retrieve the full userlist. Thank you so much.